# Allow client to edit jquery slider

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I would like to add a slider to my client's WordPress site such as owl carousel or another jquery plugin that provides a full page background slider. But I would like my client to be able to edit the slides within a WordPress dashboard.

What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact situation.

1) Install the Simple Image Widget Plugin

2) Register a new sidebar for each image https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebars

3) Under dashboard -> appearance -> widgets -> Add an image to each sidebar you created

4) Display the each sidebar in your carousel by using `<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'your-sidebar-name' ); ?>`

Works a treat!

To register sidebars as I said in step 2, just paste this into your functions.php file (this is for 3 sidebars, add more if you need more images):

```
if (function_exists('register_sidebar')) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'=> 'Banner Slide 1 Picture',
        'id' => 'image3',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ));
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'=> 'Banner Slide 2 Picture',
        'id' => 'image2',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ));
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'=> 'Banner Slide 3 Picture',
        'id' => 'image3',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ));
 }
```

Then replace your images in your html with:

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'image1' ); ?>`
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'image2' ); ?>`
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'image3' ); ?>`
```